# Javascript validation followed by reveal of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello need some help the javascript portion of this code. I have two javascript functions: one to validate that a radio check box is selected, and another to revel the "answer".  Currently, an alert is displayed if there are no selections(which is good), but then the answer is unrevealed (regardless of the selection).

Ideally, the "answer" would only be revealed only if one of the checkboxes is selected, otherwise (if nothing is selected)an alert would be sent to the page.

Here is are the two javascript functions:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("answer").style.display ="none";
    function validateForm() {
        var choice = document.getElementsByName("Question");
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             if(!(choice[i].checked)){
                alert("please selected an answer choice");
                return false;
             }
        }
    }


    function openTest() {
            document.getElementById("answer").style.display = "block";
      }
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', openTest);
</script>
```

```js
document.getElementById("answer").style.display ="none";
    function validateForm() {
        var choice = document.getElementsByName("Question");
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             if(!(choice[i].checked)){
                alert("please selected an answer choice");
                return false;
             }
        }
    }


    function openTest() {
            document.getElementById("answer").style.display = "block";
      }
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', openTest);
```

```css
        #test {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>List of Questions</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Poll Question</h1><br>


   <table>
       <form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        {% for questions in question_list %}
            <tr>
               <th> {{ questions[2] }} </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td> <input type="radio" id="UserResponse1" name="Question" value="question1">
               <label for="UserResponse1">{{ questions[3] }}</label><br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>   <input type="radio" id="UserResponse2" name="Question" value="question2">
               <label for="UserResponse2">{{ questions[4] }}</label><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>  <input type="radio" id="UserResponse3" name="Question" value="question3">
               <label for="UserResponse3">{{ questions[5]}}</label><br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>   <input type="radio" id="UserResponse4" name="Question" value="question4">
               <label for="UserResponse4">{{ questions[6] }}</label><br> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <br><button id="button">see answer </button>

                    <div id="answer">The correct answer is: {{ questions[7] }}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </form>
        {% endfor %}
   </table><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through your code made some changes in the javascript:

- Since you are calling this on submit event of the form, I added return false at the end of the function so that it won't throw any error.
- removed 3 from for loop condition, and added `choices.length` because of the condition it was looping only for 3 times whereas it should loop for 4 times since there are 4 checkboxes.
- removed the openTest function and the statement is moved inside the validateForm function.
- created a new flag `noAnswerSelectedFlag` which will detect if any answer is checked or not. Your code had a flaw that, everytime it encountered that the first element is not selected it would always show the alert which is not correct, it should only show if answer is not selected. So the flag will be set to true or false, if false then it will break the loop and come out of it and check if the flag is set to true or false, if false which means answer is selected then it will show the correct answer or else it will show alert msg.

```js
document.getElementById("answer").style.display ="none";
function validateForm() {
    var choice = document.getElementsByName("Question");
    var noAnswerSelectedFlag = false;
    // removed 3 from here and added choices.length
    for(var i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
        // check if answer checked set to true for each time it encounters unchecked radio button
        if(!(choice[i].checked)){
            noAnswerSelectedFlag = true;
        }
        // set to false if radio button is checked and break the loop so that flag won't get modified
        else {
            noAnswerSelectedFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // check the flag's value if false show the answer
    if(!noAnswerSelectedFlag) {
        document.getElementById("answer").style.display = "block";
    }
    // else display alert msg.
    else {
        alert("please select an answer.");
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

Here's the working code for you:

```js
document.getElementById("answer").style.display ="none";
function validateForm() {
    var choice = document.getElementsByName("Question");
    var noAnswerSelectedFlag = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < choice.length; i++) {
        if(!(choice[i].checked)){
            noAnswerSelectedFlag = true;
        }
        else {
            noAnswerSelectedFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!noAnswerSelectedFlag) {
        document.getElementById("answer").style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        alert("please select an answer.");
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

```css
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Poll Question</h1><br>


<table>
    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        {% for questions in question_list %}
        <tr>
            <th> {{ questions[2] }} </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="radio" id="UserResponse1" name="Question" value="question1">
                <label for="UserResponse1">{{ questions[3] }}</label><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>   <input type="radio" id="UserResponse2" name="Question" value="question2">
                <label for="UserResponse2">{{ questions[4] }}</label><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>  <input type="radio" id="UserResponse3" name="Question" value="question3">
                <label for="UserResponse3">{{ questions[5]}}</label><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>   <input type="radio" id="UserResponse4" name="Question" value="question4">
                <label for="UserResponse4">{{ questions[6] }}</label><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br><button id="button">see answer </button>

                <div id="answer">The correct answer is: {{ questions[7] }}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
</table><br><br>
```